# Least squares for trace of matrix product

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, optimization, positive-semidefinite

If I have
\begin{align}
B = {\arg \min}_{A\in\text{Sym}^d} \sum_j (\text{tr}(A X_j) -f_j)^2
\end{align}
where $f_j>0$ and $X_j$ are positive semi-definite and there are sufficient $j$ that this is not an interpolation, and $\text{Sym}^d$ is the space of symmetric $d\times d$ matrices. Can I show that $B$ must be negative definite?

Comment: Could you elaborate more on the condition "there are sufficient $j$ that this is not an interpolation"? For example, could you provide a definition of an interpolation?

Comment: $B$ is not necessarily negtative definite. Take for example $X_{1,1} = 1$ and zeros elsewhere and $f=1$. Then any matrix with $A_{1,1}=-1$ is a minimizer.

Comment: @Pheromone Sorry, I caused some confusion. I didn't finish translating it, I meant positive-definite (in my actual problem f_j are negative, and I'm seeking negative definite, which is the cause of the confusion).

Comment: @Theo For instance for d=2, if there are 3 pieces of data, so three unique X_j, and three f_j, such that X_j span the space of symmetric 2x2. Then the 3 unique entries of A give an interpolation. I.e. tr(AX_j) = f_j at all times.

I'll edit it now.